# "Obfuscating" HTML image source URL

Tags: html, url, obfuscation, rhino

I have a server that sends some URLS to an app (sort of another server) which then sends them to the web app, so they are displayed like img src="URL"
Now, I wanted the URL not to be viewable by users visiting the website.
All URLS are in fact JPEG images

So inside the app, after I take the URL, I convert the image to base64 and send it this way to the web app

```
    => img src="data:image/base64; ... "
```

Works great but ...
Now it seems that it is kinda slow, some images are like 160 Kb and take up to 20-25 seconds to convert and usually there are like 10-20 images to convert. Have any other suggestion on how to obfuscate the URLS if not like this ?
But not something overcomplicated like caching the images in the app and sending them forward or so.
The app is written using [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29)
I m thinking about multiple threads but maybe you can come up with better ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm merely curious. Why do you want to obfuscate the URLs? Users can download the image regardless of its location. Something to consider in terms of speed: does this URL obfuscation cause the image to be piped through the web app itself, whereas before, the web server could serve them up directly? Web servers like Apache or Nginx are much more efficient at sending static files that your web app will be.

Comment: This question seems to get asked every few days on SO.  The short answer is that it is impossible to obfuscate a URL.  You can make it a little more difficult for a casual user to figure out but a determined user can always figure out how to get to the file.

Comment: @jpmc26: Obfuscating the URL is required as the sever that generates and holds the images should not be directly accessed by the users of the web application.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: I saw the previous questions that were in the same field with mine, none was helpful. I know it is impossible to obfuscate the URL, that's why I came up with the base64 conversion. I am looking for some faster solution for "downloading" and base64 encoding the images. If no other alternative will show up, I'll go for the multithreading option: download and convert several images at the same time.

Comment: You're base64 encoding the data and decoding it from JavaScript?! That's a performance nightmare. Besides, the user can just screenshot the image anyway if all else fails.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not interested about the image itself, he can right click on it and save it to his localhost. I'm interested in not disclosing the image URL, the actual IP of the server where the images are generated and stored. Well it's not pure JavaScript, more of a mix of it and Java.

Comment: @Hertz Then you may be looking for the kind of set up provided by firewalling that box from the Internet and setting up a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) on a publicly exposed server (possibly the same one running your app). I'm pretty sure any major web server (Apache, Nginx, IIS) can do a reverse proxy. This does you the favor of taking the URL rewriting completely out of your hands; you just reference the URLs on the public server.

Comment: @jpmc26 Thanks, your idea sounds great. Yet I managed to fix the time problem, it was my fault. I was using concatenation at each step which involved allocating memory for the entire base64 string each time. Now it's a matter of ms instead of dozens of seconds.